# How to pivot data in SQL without using Pivot command

Tags: sql, excel, pivot

Sample of my current table:

## ID Type

1  A

1  B

2  A

2  B

2  C

Desired Output:

## ID One Two Three

1 A B *Null*

2 A B C

Basically, I want to pivot the values in column Type into new columns (One, Two, Three, etc.) and place the values in type in those columns. Each ID will only have one row instead of multiple rows.

I am NOT able to use the PIVOT statement in SQL due to perm limitations but is there another way I can create this in SQL or in Excel?

Comment: You don't have permission to use `PIVOT`, but you can query the data otherwise?

Comment: just use a pivot table in excel then

Comment: also, are you using sql server?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
select id, max(case when type='a' then type else null end) one,   max(case when type='b' then type else null end) two,
max(case when type='c' then type else null end) three
from #temp1
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the common way I've seen it done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID,
    a.Type AS "One",
    b.Type AS "Two",
    c.Type AS "Three"
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN Table a
    ON  a.ID   = t.ID
    AND a.Type = 'A'
LEFT JOIN Table b
    ON  b.ID   = t.ID
    AND b.Type = 'B'
LEFT JOIN Table c
    ON  c.ID   = t.ID
    AND c.Type = 'C'
```

It's very inefficient compared to a PIVOT.  The only advantage of this method over using the `MAX()` method supplied by @DanielMarcus is that this method works even if the column's data type doesn't support aggregation, but the aggregation method may perform better.

That said, if you have permission to SELECT then I don't see why you wouldn't have permission to PIVOT.  The only issue might be if the database you're using doesn't have it's compatibility level set to 90 (SQL Server 2005) or higher, which I believe is required.